# Full outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a following situation (table schema: `ID, first name, last name, value`).:

`table 1`:

```
ID | first name  | last name  | value
--------------------------------------
1  |    John     | Goodman    |  5
2  |    Peter    | Snow       |  6
3  |    Mike     | Walker     |  7
4  |    John     | Goodman    |  8
```

`table 2`:

```
ID | first name  | last name  | value
--------------------------------------
1  |  Peter      | Snow       | 2
2  |  Bobby      | White      | 1
3  |  Mike       | Walker     | 1
4  |  Brad       | West       | 2
5  |  Peter      | Snow       | 3
```

I want to write full outer join to get sum on 4th column, but each name should be placed only once in a result (joined) table, like this:

result table:

```
ID | first name  | last name  | value.table1 | value.table2 
-----------------------------------------------------------
1  |  John       | Goodman    | 5            | 0
2  |  Peter      | Snow       | 6            | 5
3  |  Mike       | Walker     | 7            | 1
4  |  Bobby      | White      | 0            | 1
5  |  Brad       | West       | 0            | 2
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Why John, Goodman is having 2 records in result??

Comment: ... and shoudn't Peter Snow total 11?

Comment: I fixed my question. Sorry, I rephrased it a little bit, beacuse I need values from both tables.

Comment: Do you need `ID` in the result? How is it meant to be computed when the original `ID`s from the two tables do not match?

Comment: There are still some discrepancies between your tables and the result, e.g. John Goodman that has a total of 13 in table 1, also the ID (in the result table) that has been mentioned before. Do you want to `ORDER` the result set, and by what? Try to get these questions answered before expecting a good and working solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work (if I ignore the `ID` column for now):

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(t1.FirstName,t2.FirstName) as FirstName,
    COALESCE(t1.LastName,t2.LastName) as LastName,
    COALESCE(t1.value,0) as t1value,
    COALESCE(t2.value,0) as t2value
FROM
    (select FirstName,LastName,SUM(value) as value
     from table1
     group by FirstName,LastName) t1
        full outer join
    (select FirstName,LastName,SUM(value) as value
     from table2
     group by FirstName,LastName) t2
        on
            t1.FirstName= t2.FirstName and
            t1.LastName=  t2.LastName
```

Answer (score 1):

```
With s as (Select firstname, lastname , value
From table1
Union all
Select firstname, lastname , value
From table2)
Select firstname, lastname , sum(value)
From s
Group by firstname , lastname
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT COALESCE(T1.FName,T2.FName) as FName,COALESCE(T1.LName,T2.LName) as LName,ISNULL(T1.Value,0) as Value1,ISNULL(T2.Value,0) as Value2 
FROM Table1 T1 FULL OUTER JOIN
     Table2 T2 ON T1.FName=T2.FName AND T1.LName=T2.LName
```

**Explanation:**

`COALESCE` returns the first in the list which is not `NULL`.

`ISNULL` is used to replace `NULL` values with 0.
Result:

```
FNAME   LNAME   VALUE1  VALUE2
John    Goodman 5       0
Peter   Snow    6       2
Peter   Snow    6       3
Mike    Walker  7       1
John    Goodman 8       0
Bobby   White   0       1
Brad    West    0       2
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/8f770/10).

Comment: I rephrased my question, actually, I need both columns.

Comment: @Milan: But John Goodman has 5 and 8 in table1 and 5 and 0 in the result??

Answer (score 1):

This is the working solution for mySQL, ignoring the ID column:

```
SELECT FirstName, 
       LastName, 
       SUM(tot1) 
FROM   (SELECT FirstName, 
               LastName, 
               sum(value) as tot1
        FROM   table1
        GROUP BY  FirstName, 
                  LastName
        UNION  SELECT FirstName, 
               LastName, 
               sum(value)
        FROM   table2
        GROUP BY  FirstName, 
                  LastName) t
GROUP BY  FirstName, 
          LastName
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @table1 Table (ID int, firstname varchar(30), lastname varchar(30), value int)
Declare @table2 Table (ID int, firstname varchar(30), lastname varchar(30), value int)
Insert into @table1 values 
(1,'John', 'Goodman', 5 ),
(2,'Peter', 'Snow', 6   ),
(3,'Mike', 'Walker', 7  ),
(4,'John', 'Goodman', 8 )

Insert into @table2 values 

(1, 'Peter', 'Snow', 2 ),
(2, 'Bobby', 'White', 1),
(3, 'Mike', 'Walker', 1),
(4, 'Brad', 'West', 2  ),
(5, 'Peter', 'Snow', 3 )

Select  A.*,
        ISNULL(B.value,0) [value.t1],
        ISNULL(C.value,0) [value.t2]
From    (
Select  row_number() over (order by firstname) id,*
From    (
        Select firstname,lastname from @table1
        union all
        Select firstname,lastname from @table2
        ) Lu
group   by firstname,lastname) A
Left Join (Select firstname,lastname,Min(value) value From @table1 Group By firstname,lastname) B On A.firstname = B.firstname And A.lastname = B.lastname
Left Join (Select firstname,lastname,Sum(value) value From @table2 Group By firstname,lastname) C On A.firstname = C.firstname And A.lastname = C.lastname
```

**Result**

[image]